# Strong typed URL in ASP.NET VB.NET Webforms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url, strong-typing

I'm using a strong type URLs in my ASP.NET VB.NET Application in that way:

`Resonse.Redirect(WebForm1.RealtiveURL)`

```
Public Class WebForm2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property RealtiveURL As String
        Get
            Return "~/Folder/Where/I/Am/WebForm2.aspx"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Is there another way to automatically get the relative url from a WebForm, maybe the passing the class to a function?

I found a method on internet with .tt files, but only for c#.

Comment: Do you mean like `Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath`?

Comment: Yes, BUT not from current request.

I want to know the relative url from another page to do a redirect.